# Mysql header not found even if is in a nonstandard location

Tags: mysql, makefile, header-files, configure

I follow the basically solutions to solve it, but I already had the problem.

In my `configure.ac` file I have a check for mysql:

```
AC_CHECK_HEADER([mysql/mysql.h], ,AC_MSG_ERROR([Could not find mysql headers !]))
```

and of course it complain because, as explain [here](http://openbooks.sourceforge.net/books/wga/creating-configuration.html):

> If the header files are installed in a nonstandard location, such as
>   /opt/include, and CPPFLAGS doesn't refer to that directory-for
>   example, as -I/opt/include-the AC_CHECK_HEADER macro will fail, even
>   though the files do exist on the system. However, this is an issue for
>   the system's administrator. Part of the convenience of autoconf is
>   that you, as the developer, don't need to worry about these details.

So, as developer, what's the way to go to solve it properly ?
I also put the path of real location in Makefile with `-I/usr/include/mysql`, but it continues to complain.

EDIT: as suggestd I post the `configure.ac` (the main parts):

```
useMysql=no
AC_MSG_CHECKING([whether to use mysql])
AC_ARG_ENABLE(mysql,
   [  --enable-mysql    Enable mysql support],
   [MYSQL="$enableval"]
   useMysql=yes,
   [MYSQL="no"]
)
AC_MSG_RESULT([$MYSQL])
AC_SUBST([MYSQL])

[...]

if test "$MYSQL" = "yes"; then
    AC_CHECKING([for MYSQL Library and Header files])
    AC_CHECK_HEADER([mysql/mysql.h], ,AC_MSG_ERROR([Could not find mysql headers !]))
    AC_CHECK_LIB(mysqlclient, mysql_init, [ MYSQL_LIBS="-lmysqlclient" ], [AC_MSG_ERROR([$PACKAGE_NAME requires but cannot find mysqlclient])])
    AC_DEFINE(USE_MYSQL, 1, [Use MYSQL library])
    AC_SUBST(MYSQL_LIBS)
fi
```

then I use the `MYSQL_LIBS` in the Makefile:

```
AM_CFLAGS = -g -fPIC -rdynamic -I$(top_srcdir)/include -I/usr/include/mysql
```

Comment: If the file `/usr/include/mysql/mysql.h` exists then it is *not* installed in a non-standard location and the `AC_CHECK_HEADER` will not fail. Does that file it exist? If not, where is `mysql.h`?

Comment: `find /usr/ -name 'mysql.h'` = `/usr/include/mysql/mysql.h` so your assumption is not correct. The file exist and `AC_CHECK_HEADER` fail. Might I miss something else ?

Comment: You'll need to post the whole `./configure.ac`, and how you ran `./configure [options...]`,
and the output of doing so.

Comment: What looks at least odd to me is how you are missing squared brackets within `AC_CHECK_HEADER`. The idiomatic syntax would be `AC_CHECK_HEADER([mysql/mysql.h], [], [AC_MSG_ERROR([Could not find mysql headers !])])`.